# Subspaces of a Subfactor

Tags: subfactors, von-neumann-algebras, oa.operator-algebras

Is the following true?

> Let $\mathcal N \subset \mathcal M$ be a subfactor. There is a bijective correspondence between the ultraweakly closed subspaces of $\mathcal M$ that are bimodules over $\mathcal N'\cap \mathcal M$, and the ultraweakly closed subspaces of $\mathcal N$.

If the statement is false, is there a simple way to modify it to make it true? I am particularly interested in the case that $\mathcal M$ is of type $\mathrm I$.

If $\mathcal V \subseteq \mathcal N$ is ultraweakly closed, then $\mathcal V (\mathcal N' \cap \mathcal M)$ is a bimodule over $\mathcal N'\cap \mathcal M$. If the subfactor admits a conditional expectation, then this function is injective. (**Edit.** Jesse points out that the conditional expectation should be ultrweakly continuous.)

**Edit.** Steven points out that the statement as written is trivially true by a counting argument. Of course, I'm asking about the function $\mathcal V \mapsto \mathcal V \mathcal (\mathcal N'\cap \mathcal M)$, or something similarly natural. He also notes that irreducible subfactors are a counterexample to the bijectivity of $\mathcal V \mapsto \mathcal V(\mathcal N' \cap\mathcal M )$ in general. This leaves a single concrete question:

> Let $\mathcal N \subseteq \mathcal B (\mathcal H)$ be a factor. Is the function $\mathcal V \mapsto \mathcal V \mathcal N'$ a bijection between the ultraweakly closed subspaces of $\mathcal N$ and the ultraweakly closed subspaces of $\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$ that are $\\mathcal N'$ bimodules?

Comment: What is $\mathcal V (\mathcal N' \cap \mathcal M)$?  Is this the algebraic span of $\mathcal V$ and $(\mathcal N' \cap \mathcal M)$ or are you taking the closure in some topology?

Comment: This is a nice question, Andre. Thanks for asking! If N is a type I factor, we should be able to decompose B(H) as N⊗N′. Of course N′ is also type I. We can get the identity as a strong-operator limit of finite rank operators in N′, should it be infinite dimensional. The compact operators feel like the only obstruction for doing what you want in this case. Your map should be bijective in the type I case...

Comment: @ Jesse: I mean the ultraweak closure.

Comment: This question is keeping me awake. Let me type an answer. I think the idea is that the conditional expectation onto the first copy should leave the subspace alone...

Comment: @ Jon: Thank you. Yes, I think the map is bijective if both factors are of type $\mathrm I$, for the reason that you give.

Comment: Thanks, and why is the the function $\mathcal V \mapsto \mathcal V (\mathcal N' \cap \mathcal M)$ 1-1 if there is a conditional expectation from $\mathcal M$ to $\mathcal N$?  For instance, what if $\mathcal N = R$ is the amenable $II_1$ factor and $\mathcal M = \mathcal B(L^2 R)$?  If $\mathcal V$ is any irreducible subfactor in $R$ then doesn't it follow from von Neumann's bicommutant theorem that $\mathcal V ( R' \cap \mathcal B(L^2R) ) = \mathcal B(L^2R)$?

Comment: @ Jesse: Let $E: \mathcal M \rightarrow \mathcal N$ be a conditional expectation. For all $m \in \mathcal N' \cap \mathcal M$ and $n \in \mathcal N$, $nE(m)= E(nm) = E(mn)= E(m)n$, so $E(m) \in \mathcal N' \cap \mathcal N = \mathbb C$. It follows that $E(\mathcal V(\mathcal N' \cap \mathcal M)) = \mathcal V E(\mathcal N'\cap \mathcal M) = \mathcal V$. Thus, the function $\mathcal V \mapsto \mathcal V (\mathcal N' \cap \mathcal M)$ is injective. I may be missing something.

Comment: I see Andre, thank you.  Since you are taking $\mathcal V( \mathcal N' \cap \mathcal M)$ to be weakly closed, in order for the equality $E(\mathcal V( \mathcal N' \cap \mathcal M)) = \mathcal V E(\mathcal N' \cap \mathcal M)$ you will need that $E$ is ultraweakly continuous.  In the example I gave in my previous comment the conditional expectation is not ultraweakly continuous.

Comment: @ Jesse: Ah, I see. I imagined that an expectation would be ultraweakly continuous by definition. Could you suggest a reference?

Comment: A good reference might be Section IV.2 of Blackadar's "Operator algebras" (http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2188261).  Of particular interest to you might be Theorem IV.2.2.3 which shows that if there is an ultraweakly continuous conditional expectation from $\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$ to $\mathcal N$, then $\mathcal N$ is type I.

Comment: I still don't have a normal conditional expectation onto the type I subfactor...so all we know is what you guys have put together above: that the map is invertible (on its range) if there is a normal conditional expectation. Perhaps in the type I case this is clear, but I don't see it yet.

Comment: @ Jesse: Thank you.
@ Jon: Since each type $\mathrm I$ subfactor of $\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$ looks like $\mathcal B(\mathcal H_1)$ with $\mathcal H = \mathcal H_1 \tensor \mathcal H_2$, it seems to me that $1 \tensor \phi$ is an ultraweakly continuous conditional expectation onto $B(\mathcal H_1)$ if $\phi$ is a normal state. 

Comment: @Andre: I now believe that much should be fine. I talked to Don Hadwin to see if there was another way to see the normal cond. exp. and he came up with another neat way to see it: If you view $\mathcal{H}$ as you show above, view $B(\mathcal{H})$ as matrices over $B(\mathcal{H_{1}})$, now send a matrix to the "block" diagonal matrix formed by propagating the upper left hand entry.  

Comment: @Jesse: (responding to your earlier comment): The surjectivity doesn't work *at all*...so that remains an intuition.

Comment: @Jon: Do you know what happens to your question in finite dimension? If I am right, $M=N\otimes Q$, $A=N'\cap M=1\otimes Q$.  If $p$ is a projection from $M$ onto an $A,A$-subbimodule of $M$, then $p\in A'\cap JA'J\subset B(L^2(M))$. Write $B(L^2(M))=N\otimes N^{op}\otimes Q\otimes Q^{op}$; then $p\in N\otimes N^op\subset B(L^2(M))$, if we identify $N$ (resp. $N^op$) with subsets of $B(L^2(M))$ via left (resp. right) multiplication. Thus indeed $p$ is a projection in $B(L^2(N))$.  Same proof works in type I, but you have to take your subbimodule in $B(L^2(M))$ (i.e., $B(HS(H))$ if $M=B(H)$).

Comment: @Dima:  I think it might be a bit more subtle in the infinite dimensional case.  In that case there isn't a canonical way to embed subspaces of $M$ into $L^2(M)$ and this may cause problems.  At least, I do not see immediately how to get around this. 

Comment: @Jesse: Perhaps, though, we can at least naturally embed $M \otimes M^{op}$ into $HS(M)$ as finite-rank operators...

Comment: @Jon:  I don't see what you mean, please explain.

Comment: @Jon:  $M$ is not a Hilbert space and so I do not know what you mean by $HS(M)$. If $M = \mathcal B(\mathcal H)$ then we do have a natural Hilbert-space isomorphism $L^2(M) \cong HS(\mathcal H) \cong \mathcal H \overline \otimes \mathcal H$. See for example the wikipedia entry on Hilbert-Schmidt operators (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator).

Comment: @Jesse: This helps. I've been conflating the case of finite von Neumann algebras, where we can think of elements of $M$ as Hilbert space vectors. Above HS(M) was meant to be $HS(L^2(M))=L^2(M)\otimesL^2(M^{op})$ and I wanted the natural embedding of $M$ into L^{2}(M) as in the finite vN alg. case. Now I see the trouble a bit more clearly... 

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the statement is true because the set of ultraweakly-closed subspaces of $N$ has the same cardinality as the set of $N^\prime\cap M$-bimodular subsets of $M$. You probably want an explicit description of the correspondence, preferably such that the $N^\prime\cap M$-bimodule that corresponds to $V\subset N$ is exactely $V(N^\prime\cap M)$.

This is certainly not true in general. For an irreducible subfactor $N\subset M$, i.e. $N^\prime\cap M=\C$, the condition that $V\subset M$ is an $N^\prime\cap M$-bimodule is empty, while there are strictly more subsets of $M$.

Of course, the bicommutant theorem shows that there are no irreducible subfactors of type I factors. I do not immediately see a counterexample in the type I case.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Irreducible subfactors came up as a counterexample to one of my previous questions, but I managed to completely forget about them! Since I'm interested primarily in the type $\mathrm I$ case, I'd like to wait until that part of the question is resolved.